# PIG with -tagsource option behaves weird

Tags: apache-pig

I am using the -tagsource option while loading the input data in order to
identify the input source. It seems that, later while I project only
selected fields from the input tuple, there are some assumptions and
certain fields get projected all the time though I try to ignore them.

Take a look at my script.

> rawdata = load 'data/201212*' using PigStorage(' ', '-tagsource') as
> (filename:chararray, ts: int, ip: chararray, domain: chararray,
> answer: chararray);
>
> A = foreach rawdata generate ts, ip, domain, answer,
> CONCAT(CONCAT(filename, '_'), UPPER(SUBSTRING(domain, 0, 1))) as
> domain_index, filename as filename;
>
> B = foreach A generate ip as ip, SUBSTRING(domain, 0, 1) as
> domain_first_char, filename;
>
> dump A;
>
> dump B;
>
> ILLUSTRATE B;

While creating B, I am trying to include only selected fields from A.
However, if I dump B, the 'ts' field (the first field in A) keeps appearing
in B. But in ILLUSTRATE B, everything looks nice as expected.

> Dump of A:
>
> (100,123.98.11.123,google.com,{(google)},20121201_G,20121201)
>
> (95,500.98.11.123,yahoo.com,{(yahoo)},20121201_Y,20121201)
>
> (107,123.98.11.123,google.com,{(google)},20121201_G,20121201)
>
> (156,123.98.11.123,cnn.com,{(cnn)},20121201_C,20121201)
>
> Dump of B:
>
> (100,g,20121201)
>
> (95,y,20121201)
>
> (107,g,20121201)
>
> (156,c,20121201)

ILLUSTRATE B:

> B  | ip:chararray | domain_first_char:chararray  | filename:chararray
>
> | 123.98.11.123 | g  | 20121202

As seen in Dump B, instead of printing the ip value as the first field (as
in illustrate B), it prints the ts field.

Answer (score 0):

Searching around the internet, I found that this is a bug in PigStorage and found a workaround.

Starting pig with the flag `-t ColumnMapKeyPrune` helps fixing this issue i.e., start pig using the command `pig -x local -t ColumnMapKeyPrune sample.pig`.

Thanks to [Reremiah Rounds](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pig-user/201208.mbox/%3CCAOjnRsY99p1+z2W10Zp6UjOPGjU-MGNjgfU0eMjoBRqG0ojoOQ@mail.gmail.com%3E) of pig user group.